# use javascript function in xslt 1.0

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-1.0, web-parts

I have a problem calling javascript function in xslt 1.0.

here my code:

```css
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt user"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
  xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
    function datetimezone() {
    return "A B C";
    }
  </msxsl:script>
```

and

```css
<xsl:value-of select="user:datetimezone()" />
```

my webpartcrashed and I can't see where. I search in this forum some answers like my problem but I can't see any error. Someone can write a simple example or a way to do this?

In fact, I have to convert 06/03/2015 22:00 to local time zone.

Thanks.

Comment: Your Javascript function does not have any arguments, yet your XSLT function call passes in an argument `@Date`. That does not make sense. And we really would need to see the context of your XML input and of the stylesheet as otherwise we can't tell what `@Date` selects.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I try it without "@Date" and without parameters and my webparts still crash.

Comment: Is the date string being parsed assumed to be GMT, that you want to parse and then emit the local time?

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen Date is a Datetime that I can convert with select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime, but I want to emit the local time against this datetime. Thanks for the answer.